# Unity 2D C# How can I can make object facing coordinates on click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, coordinates, transform

I want to make a simple C# script for unity (2D). I want to rotate an object (image) slowly in the direction I clicked with mouse. I was looking long for it and only found how to rotate it slowly in known direction, and how to rotate in there where I click, but it's not slowly. I tried to combine those two mechanics but nothing works. Here's my current piece of code:

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);

void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            destinationX = clicked('x');
            destinationY = clicked('Y');
            direction = new Vector2(clicked('x') - transform.position.x, clicked('y') - transform.position.y);
        }

        transform.Rotate(new Vector3() * Time.deltaTime * 10.2f, Space.World);
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f;
    }

    float clicked(char axis)
    {
        if (axis == 'x')
        {
            return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
        }
        else
        {
            return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y;
        }
    }
```

I know it became very messy and I don't know if everything is even used because I lost my mind looking for an answer (that's why I'm here).

**Please help, and Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `new Vector3()` as argument to `Rotate`.

This equals using `new Vector3(0,0,0)` so no matter with what ever you multiply this it will stay `0,0,0` => you are not rotating the object on any axis.

---

You probably rather want to use e.g. [`Mathf.Atan2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html) which will give you the Z rotation in order to look at a position X,Y **relative to your objects position** (== direction).

The returned value is in **radians** so additionally you have to multiply it by [`Mathf.Rad2Deg`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Rad2Deg.html).
Knowing now the required angle on the Z axis you can use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) to generate a `Quaternion` from that angle and store it (= targetRotation).

Finally you can use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) in order to rotate smoothly with a **linear speed** against that target rotation without overshooting.

```
// Adjust these via the Inspector
// In angle per second
[SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 10.2f;
// In Units per second
[SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 0.2f;

// If possible assign via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

private void Awake ()
{
    // As fallback get ONCE
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;

    targetRotation = transform.rotation;
}


private Quaternion targetRotation;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Instead of 4 repeated calls store this ONCE
        // directly use Vector2, you don't care about the Z axis
        Vector2 destination = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        // directly use the Vector2 substraction for getting the direction vector without the Z axis
        Vector2 direction = destination - (Vector2)transform.position;

        // Use Atan2 to get the target angle in radians
        // therefore multiply by Rad2Deg to get degrees
        var zAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        // Store the target rotation
        targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0, zAngle);
    }

    // Rotate smoothly with linear rotationSpeed against the targetRotation
    // this prevents any overshooting
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    // In 2D you most probably do not want to move forward which is the Z axis but rather e.g. right on the X axis
    transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well... but somehow when I changed rotationSpeed and movementSpeed it didn't actually get faster... also it doesn't move other like than rotating.

Comment: oh sorry... it moves forward but in z direction so I didn't see... also how can I change to make forward as only x and y and not z?

Comment: @DEMON use `transform.right` instead of `transform.forward`

Comment: but won't it move just in right direction? I mean if it won't just move to the right of screen? Anyway I'll try it, so thanks!

Comment: well `forward` usually is the Z axis ... if you only want the `x` or `y` axis it should probably father be `transform.right` or `transform.up`

Comment: Thank you! It really works with ```transform.right```!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quaternion.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) to smoothly rotate an object.

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
```

You can also use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) for the position

Comment: I wrote ```transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation.z, direction, Time.time * 3.0f);``` and got an error that I can't convert  from UnityEgine.Vector2 to UnityEngine.Quaterion (arg 2) and can't convert from float to UnityEngine.Quaterion
What shall I do now?

Comment: also  I didn't have any error when instead of 3.0f was speed except that speed doesn't exist

Comment: I changed it and got or none errors(```transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, transform.rotation, Time.time * 3.0f);``` and nothing moved (because it was nowhere to move I think) or 1 error (```transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, direction, Time.time * 3.0f);```)... What should I do to make direction valid for this method?